# select random unique records from mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to fetch `random` records from `mysql` database , which it worked but i need the records to be also `unique` when i fetch them as they duplicated on the output, here is my code:

```
    <?

for ($counter = 1; $counter <=5;$counter++) 
{

$randomPostSelect = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM beventreservation WHERE (beventStatus='online' OR beventStatus='soldout') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());

$fetchPosts = mysql_fetch_array($randomPostSelect) or die(mysql_error());


echo '<li><a href="reservation.php?rev='.$fetchPosts['eventId'].'">'.$fetchPosts['eventTitle'].'</a></li>';
echo '</br>';
}


?>
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: Write your sql query outside the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the code in a for loop including the code that runs the query; you "extract" 5 rows from db but only fetch the first, and repeat this 5 times. Instead you should run the query once, then loop on your results until you reach the end of the `results`:

```
<?
$randomPostSelect = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM beventreservation 
        WHERE (beventStatus='online' OR beventStatus='soldout') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5")
    or die(mysql_error());

while ($fetchPosts = mysql_fetch_array($randomPostSelect))
{
    echo '<li><a href="reservation.php?rev='.$fetchPosts['eventId'].'">'.$fetchPosts['eventTitle']
        .'</a </li>';
    echo '</br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks :) , i just figure out that before 10 seconds :) , thank you for your time .